# a Batch file that uses nircmd.exe

Tags: c++, qt, cmd, exe, qprocess

i'm trying to run a batch file using qt, the batch file is using nircmd.exe program and looks like this:

```
@echo off
nircmd setprimarydisplay 2
timeout /t 10
nircmd setprimarydisplay 1
exit
```

and i'm trying to run this line in QT:

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd", QStringList() << "/c" << "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\tmp.bat");
```

when i'm running my QT code it says "'nircmd' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

The nircmd.exe is located in c:\windows\system32, the the computer path is detecting to the right spot.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you start the batch file manually from the command line?

Comment: The x86/x64 architecture mismatch could be an issue.

Comment: when i'm starting it from the command line it does work. only when i'm using qt it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out, the problem was in the .bat file it supposed to look like this:

```
c:\windows\system32\nircmd setprimarydisplay 2
```

Comment: `c:\windows\system32` should be in your path. If this solves your problem, you're having issues with the `PATH` environment variable. Try printing it in the batch file to figure out what it contains.

Comment: the PATH wasn't the problem.
when you try to run a bat file from qt or cmd commands it could make a problem and not be able to find nircmd(in this case) bacause my OS is 64 bit, so it looking for nircmd.exe in

     c:\windows\sysWOW64

instead